# Question about the definition of divisor sum functions at 0

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was working on convolution sums of divisor sum functions, and found it very curious that some authors would define the function at 0 as:

$$\sigma_k(0):= {1\over 2}\zeta(-k)$$

But I cannot understand why. Based on my search, this definition could be first introduced by Ramanujan at 1916 on his paper "On Certian Arithmetical Functions", but no explanation was given.

It would be most helpful if someone could provide some insights or references, thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO! You should look up Eisenstein series and their q-expansion.

Comment: @Aurel Thanks for commenting! I am actually learning Eisenstein series in order to understand some other results, I will make sure to check it out.